# Expect ")" where "}" is located

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I know I'm just missing something, but I can't figure out what it is...

IntelliJ gives me an error, saying " ',' or ')' expected" at the **}** and " ') expect' / '; expected " at the ****}****. I put in some code to make sure it wasn't just freeking out at the lack of code in the brackets, but to no avail. I have also tried adding / taking away }s bc I know I sometimes forget to do them properly. It appears everything is closed as far as I can tell, can someone tell me what I'm missing?

```
public class Main extends Activity { 
// create buttons and textviews

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);
// call buttons and textviews, set default text for textviews

        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View view) {
                String textvar1 = String.valueOf(textview1.getText());
                int tv1 = Integer.parseInt(textvar1);
                int tv1m = tv1 - 1;
                textview1.setText(tv1m);
            }

        **}**

        ****}****
}
```

Comment: Take your two hands and try to match corresponding  `{` and `}` on your screen. Then do the same thing for `(` and `)`.

Comment: A practical way of tracking down this sort of problem is to print out the code and draw a line connecting each "(" to the corresponding ")".

Comment: I haven't used IntelliJ, but I'd expect it to have bracket highlighting. Move your cursor to each `{` and `(` and see which `}` or `)` it corresponds to.

Answer (score 1):

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View view) {
            String textvar1 = String.valueOf(textview1.getText());
            int tv1 = Integer.parseInt(textvar1);
            int tv1m = tv1 - 1;
            textview1.setText(tv1m);
        }

    }); //you were missing this bracket right here
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `setOnClickListener` should look like:

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View view) {
        String textvar1 = String.valueOf(textview1.getText());
        int tv1 = Integer.parseInt(textvar1);
        int tv1m = tv1 - 1;
        textview1.setText(tv1m);
    }
});
```

You have to close the `}` from `onClick` and then close the `)` from the parameters of `setOnClickListener`, and finally add a `;` to end the sentence:

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){... anonymous class body... });
```